# displaying picture by clicking an item from the listbox items

Tags: python, image, tkinter, listbox, python-imaging-library

does anyone know or have any idea how can I display the picture by selecting an item from the listbox and displaying it to the frame_3? here is the whole code for the reference and the picture provided below should be the expected output of the program, thank you, any insights are very much appreciated. [image: Expected Output]

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import position, right
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("LT_DelosSantosCristianJay")
root.geometry("500x200")



#FRAMES
frame_1 = Frame(root)
frame_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
frame_2 = Frame(root)
frame_2.grid(row = 1, column = 0,pady=(0,20))
frame_3 = Frame(root)
frame_3.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

continents = {
    "Asia": ["Philippines", "Malaysia", "Taiwan", "Singapore", "Thailand", "India"],

    "Africa": ["Algeria", "Angola", "Egypt", "Cape Verde", "Liberia", "Kenya", "Morocco", "Nigeria"],

    "America": ["Venezuela", "Peru", "Jamaica", "United States", "Cuba", "Chile", "Argentina"],

    "Europe": ["Russia", "Germany", "United Kingdom", "Italy", "Ukraine", "France", "Belgium"]
}

# Frame One

var = StringVar()
var.set('Select')

Radiobutton(frame_1, text="Asia", font=("Times", 12, "bold"), fg="blue", variable=var, value='Asia', borderwidth=1,
            relief=SOLID, width=10, command=lambda: RadioSelected(var.get())).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(frame_1, text="Africa", font=("Times", 12, "bold"), fg="blue", variable=var, value="Africa", borderwidth=1,
            relief=SOLID, width=11, command=lambda: RadioSelected(var.get())).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(frame_1, text="America", font=("Times", 12, "bold"), fg="blue", variable=var, value="America", borderwidth=1,
            relief=SOLID, width=11, command=lambda: RadioSelected(var.get())).pack(side=LEFT)
Radiobutton(frame_1, text="Europe", font=("Times", 12, "bold"), fg="blue", variable=var, value="Europe", borderwidth=1,
            relief=SOLID, width=11, command=lambda: RadioSelected(var.get())).pack(side=LEFT)

# Frame Two

# Listbox and Scrollbar
flag_listbox = Listbox(frame_2, font=("Times",15,"bold"),width=15,height=7)
flag_listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

flag_scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame_2)
flag_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

flag_listbox.config(yscrollcommand=flag_scrollbar.set)

flag_scrollbar.config(command=flag_listbox.yview)


# Radio Button click
def RadioSelected(Value):
    flag_listbox.delete(0, END)
    list_values = continents[Value]
    for i in list_values:
        flag_listbox.insert(END, i)

#Frame Three

    

#ASIA
Philippines = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Asia/PH.png"))
#Malaysia = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Asia/Malaysia.png"))
#Singapore = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Asia/Singapore.png"))
#Taiwan = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Asia/taiwan.png"))
#Thailand = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Asia/Thailand.png"))

flagbox_1 = Label(frame_3,bg="white",width=320,height=150,image=Philippines)
flagbox_1.grid(sticky="we",pady=(0,20))

#flagbox_2 = Label(frame_3,bg="white",width=320,height=150,image=Malaysia)
#flagbox_2.grid(sticky="we",pady=(0,20))

#flagbox_3 = Label(frame_3,bg="white",width=320,height=150,image=Singapore)
#flagbox_3.grid(sticky="we",pady=(0,20))

#flagbox_4 = Label(frame_3,bg="white",width=320,height=150,image=Taiwan)
#flagbox_4.grid(sticky="we",pady=(0,20))

#flagbox_5 = Label(frame_3,bg="white",width=320,height=150,image=Thailand)
#flagbox_5.grid(sticky="we",pady=(0,20))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It shouldn't be so hard, if you can map the continents to theyr flag image location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do. You can change the data-structure of your items and follow a pattern as such:

```
continents = {
    "Continent 1": [
        {'Country 1': image_for_country_1},
        {'Country 2': image_for_country_2},
        {'Country 3': image_for_country_3},
        # Other countries
    ],

    "Continent 2": [
        {'Country 4': image_for_country_4},
        {'Country 5': image_for_country_5},
        {'Country 6': image_for_country_6},
        # Other countries
    ],

    # Other continents
}
```

So in your case, the dictionary must be structured in some way like:

```
Philippines = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Asia/PH.png"))
Malaysia = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Asia/Malaysia.png"))
# Define image for all the other countries

continents = {
    "Asia": [
        {"Philippines": Philippines},
        {"Malaysia": Malaysia}, 
        # Same pattern as above for other countries
    ],
    
    "Africa": [
        {"Algeria": Algeria}, 
        {"Angola": Angola}, 
        # Same pattern as above for other countries
    ],
    
    # Same pattern as above for other continents
}
```

Now you will have to change the way your items are inserted into the listbox because you changed your dictionary structure:

```
def RadioSelected(Value):
    flag_listbox.delete(0, END)
    list_values = continents[Value]
    for i in list_values:
        flag_listbox.insert(END, list(i.keys())[0])
```

Now remove your each individual flag labels and just have a single flag label/holder:

```
flagbox = Label(frame_3,bg="white",width=320,height=150, image=Philippines)
flagbox.grid(sticky="we",pady=(0,20))
```

...and now you have to bind to the listbox such that when an item is selected in the listbox, you will run a function that will change image:

```
def callback(event):
    continent = var.get() # Get the continent
    country = flag_listbox.get(flag_listbox.curselection()) # Get the country
    countries = continents[continent] # Get the list of countries in the selected continent
    
    for each_country in countries: # Loop through the list
        if country in each_country: # Check if the country exist in dictionary, then
            img = list(each_country.values()) # Get the image from the dictionary
            flagbox.config(image=img) # Update the image
            break # Break the loop from going further

flag_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',callback) # Bind the listbox
```

This should be able to change the image each time an item is selected from the listbox.

Comment: thank you very much sir this helped me so much I've finished the code now and I'm glad to say that I passed my 1st year college because of your help and I've added a few things to the code and resized the pictures so that it will fit the app's size, thank you again good sir :)) @Delrius Euphoria